# Why does my QItemDelegate not correctly allow checkboxs to be checked or unchecked in my QTableWidget?

Tags: pyside6

I am trying to use a QItemDelegate to make clickable check boxes in one column in my QTableWidget. However, they are not working. I edited the code from another SO question (can not find it to link) so that bool's are used instead of ints. I have tried various things such as messing around with the `paint` and `editorEvent` methods of the QItemDelegate to no avail. I can tell they are being called and the data in the DataFrame is being set but that it about it. I suspect the model is somehow conflicting with the QItemDelegate Can anyone guide me through how I might debug this as I am still new to Pyside6? I do want to use a Delegate, rather than using the Model to create the checkboxes.

Here is my code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QEvent, QModelIndex, QMetaObject
from PySide6.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QItemDelegate, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QHeaderView, QTableView
import pandas as pd


class CheckBoxDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return None

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # Draw a check if it is True else, do not draw a check.
        self.drawCheck(painter, option, option.rect,
                       Qt.CheckState.Checked if index.data() else Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        # TODO: figure out why QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable can not be converted to int. It is not one of QT's EnumInts that much is clear.
        # if not int((index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable)) > 0:
        #     return False

        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease and event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            # Change the checkbox-state
            self.setModelData(None, model, index)
            return True

        return False

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, not index.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole), Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole)

class OverallHeaderView(QHeaderView):
    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex):
        painter.save()
        painter.restore()
        # Set the fill color
        brush = QBrush(QColor('#0078D7'))
        brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        # Set the outline color
        painter.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        painter.drawRect(rect)

        value = self.model().headerData(logicalIndex, Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        painter.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, value)


class OverviewTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OverviewTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._filters = {}
        self._sortBy = []
        self._sortDirection = []
        self._dfSource = pd.DataFrame()
        self._dfDisplay = pd.DataFrame()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dfDisplay.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dfDisplay.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return self._dfDisplay.values[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation=Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal and role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._dfDisplay.columns[col])
        return None

    def setupModel(self, data):
        self._dfSource = data
        self._sortBy = []
        self._sortDirection = []
        self.setFilters({})

    def setFilters(self, filters):
        self.modelAboutToBeReset.emit()
        self._filters = filters
        self.updateDisplay()
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def updateDisplay(self):

        dfDisplay = self._dfSource.copy()

        # Filtering
        cond = pd.Series(True, index=dfDisplay.index)
        for column, value in self._filters.items():
            cond = cond & \
                   (dfDisplay[column].str.lower().str.find(str(value).lower()) >= 0)
        dfDisplay = dfDisplay[cond]

        # Sorting
        if len(self._sortBy) != 0:
            dfDisplay.sort_values(by=self._sortBy,
                                  ascending=self._sortDirection,
                                  inplace=True)

        # Updating
        self._dfDisplay = dfDisplay

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            column_name = self._dfSource.columns[index.column()]
            if column_name == 'Watch List':
                return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled


class OverviewFilteringView(object):
    def setupUi(self, OverviewTableWidget):
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(OverviewTableWidget)
        self.tableView = QTableView(OverviewTableWidget)
        self.tableView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(OverviewTableWidget)

        # Create our custom header view and set the headers to resize to contents
        self.header_view = OverallHeaderView(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.tableView.setHorizontalHeader(self.header_view)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)



class OverviewTableWidget(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(OverviewTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = OverviewFilteringView()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # TODO: should this be somewhere else?
        # Set up our list column
        # Load the watch list from JSON file


        chore_list = [
            {
                'Name': 'Laundry'
            },
            {
                'Name': 'Clean'
            }
        ]

        data['Watch List'] = data['Name'].apply(
            lambda chore: any(record.get('Name') == chore for record in chore_list )
        )

        self.tableModel = OverviewTableModel()
        self.tableModel.setupModel(data)
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel)

        # Make the description column hidden <- adaptive based on changing column numbers
        for x in range(self.tableModel.columnCount()):
            header_text = self.tableModel.headerData(x)
            # Ensure the Watch List has the Delegate
            elif header_text == 'Watch List':
                self.ui.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(x, CheckBoxDelegate())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Task': [1, 2, 3],
        'Name': ['Clean', "Sweep", 'Dishes']
    })
    
    table = OverviewTableWidget(data)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: "the data in the DataFrame is being set": that is quite impossible, since you've never implemented [`setData()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData). And this is just the tip of the iceberg, because your code has **a lot** of issues (including the fact that it's not reproducible). For instance, adding a QTableView *inside* a QTableWidget is complete ***nonsense***. It seems like you're randomly putting together snippets of code you found here and there without really thinking (and knowing) about what they do. As already suggested, take your time and **study** the documentation.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to at least click the link to accept the duplicate proposal, even though, a better choice would be to completely delete this post, as it's unlikely it would ever be helpful to anybody else, due to its irreproducibility and the issues its code contains, which may potentially lead another beginner to think that, besides the problem at hand, everything else you did is acceptable. Which, and forgive me if I'm blunt, is definitely not.